# Postgresql: Remove last char in text-field if the column ends with minus sign

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to remove the last char in a column if it ends with the minus sign.
How could I do this in postgresql?

For example:

```
sdfs-dfg4t-etze45z5z- => sdfs-dfg4t-etze45z5z
gsdhfhsfh-rgertggh => stay untouched
```

Is there an easy syntax I can use?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the trim function if all trailing dashes can be removed, or use regexp_replace if you need only the last dash removed.  Trim probably performs better than regexp_replace.

```
with strings as
(
    select 'sdfs-dfg4t-etze45z5z-' as string union all
    select 'sdfs-dfg4t-etze45z5z--' as string union all
    select 'gsdhfhsfh-rgertggh'
)
select
    string,
    trim(trailing '-' from string) as all_trimmed,
    regexp_replace(string, '-$', '') as one_trimmed
from
    strings
```

Result:

```
string                  all_trimmed           one_trimmed
sdfs-dfg4t-etze45z5z-   sdfs-dfg4t-etze45z5z  sdfs-dfg4t-etze45z5z
sdfs-dfg4t-etze45z5z--  sdfs-dfg4t-etze45z5z  sdfs-dfg4t-etze45z5z-
gsdhfhsfh-rgertggh      gsdhfhsfh-rgertggh    gsdhfhsfh-rgertggh
```

Comment: update table set column = regexp_replace(column,'-$','') where column ~ '-$'

Comment: @Gavin some explanation would be great :)

Comment: The trim() solution is also quite useful when you need to work on (the end of a) text returned by a function, where using substr() and length() is not (easily) possible.

Answer (score 6):

use `regexp_replace(your_field, '-+$', '');`