# sql-remove dashes from string column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

in stored procedure, i have this field

```
LTRIM(ISNULL(O.Column1, ''))
```

If there is a dash(-) symbol at end of the value, want to remove it. only in conditions if a dash symbol exist at start/end.

Any suggestions

EDIT:

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 12.0.5546.0

Expected output:

```
1)input: "abc-abc" //output: "abc-abc"

2)input: "abc-" //output: "abc"

3)input: "abc" //ouput: "abc"
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be stuck with string manipulation here.

The `CASE` expression here takes the `LTRIM/RTRIM` result from your column and checks both ends for a dash, and then each end for a dash. If dashes exist, it strips them out. It's not pretty, and won't perform well on a mountain of data, but will do what you need.

Data setup:

```
create table trim (col1 varchar(10));

insert trim (col1)
values
  ('abc'),
  (' abc-'),
  ('abc- '),
  ('abc-abc '),
  (' -abc'),
  ('-abc '),
  (NULL),
  (''),
  (' -abc- ');
```

The query:

```
select 
 case 
    when right(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(col1,''))),1) = '-'
     and left(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(col1,''))),1) = '-'
      then substring(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(col1,''))),2,len(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(col1,''))))-2)
    when right(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(col1,''))),1) = '-'
      then left(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(col1,''))), len(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(col1,''))))-1)
    when left(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(col1,''))),1) = '-'
      then right(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(col1,''))), len(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(col1,''))))-1)
    else ltrim(rtrim(isnull(col1,'')))
  end as trimmed
from trim;
```

Results:

```
+---------+
| trimmed |
+---------+
| abc     |
| abc     |
| abc     |
| abc-abc |
| abc     |
| abc     |
|         |
|         |
| abc     |
+---------+
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b9a70/5/0)

Comment: Why is string-manipulation in T-SQL so dosh-darned _user-hostile_? It's been this way for decades. We still don't even have real regular-expression support or intermediate variables in column expressions and support for inlining scalar UDFs is finicky. It feels like a _cursed place_.

Comment: @Dai, there are about 10 years between me an retirement, so as long as they keep it user-hostile for one more decade, I'll take that job security. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the Database is not mentioned, here is how you do it (rather find it)

SQL Server

[Remove the last character in a string in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256915/remove-the-last-character-in-a-string-in-t-sql)

Oracle

[Remove last character from string in sql plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465848/remove-last-character-from-string-in-sql-plus)

Postgresql

[Postgresql: Remove last char in text-field if the column ends with minus sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461891/postgresql-remove-last-char-in-text-field-if-the-column-ends-with-minus-sign)

MySQL

[Strip last two characters of a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080662/strip-last-two-characters-of-a-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT function, along with SUBSTRING to achieve the result.

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT(stringVal,1)= '-' THEN SUBSTRING(stringVal,1,LEN(stringVal)-1) 
ELSE stringVal END AS ModifiedString 
from
( VALUES ('abc-abc'), ('abc-'),('abc')) as t(stringVal)
```

```
+----------------+
| ModifiedString |
+----------------+
| abc-abc        |
| abc            |
| abc            |
+----------------+
```